# Problems in partitoning the hard disk using Gparted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I was trying to increase the size of my Ubuntu(ext4) using Gparted, and while I managed to increase the size to 270GB I noticed that I have too much unallocated space. I am attaching the image below(sorry for the poor quality).
As you can see I have created, foolishly, three ext4 partitions but the one that my Ubuntu uses is sdb5. Also, sdb4 and sdb7 are partitions for D and E of my Windows OS. Now, is this somehow possible to use all the unallocated space I have to be merged with ext4(sdb5)? I am ready to sacrifice D and E.
Please help, I would be really grateful.

PS - please do not flag this as duplicate as I wasn't able to find a solution. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how would I delete and recreate Linux-swap. Can I move ext4(sdb5) below Linux-swap somehow?

Comment: @guiverc some of your comments are not complete, or just blatantly incorrect. Space outside of an extended partition **can** be used inside the extended partition. Recreating a swap partition/file requires editing **two** files. Swap **is** used during the boot process. Etc.

Comment: @NikhilShrivastava you need to clear up some parts of your question. "sdb5 and sdb7 are partitions for D and E of my Windows OS" can't be correct, as sdb5 is Ubuntu. If you use Windows at all, you should consider adding some/all of the unallocated space to sdb2. What version of Windows do you have? If it's W10, you may have a problem with W10 updates wiping out ext4 partitions on a MBR disk. Does your machine allow UEFI booting, or only legacy MBR? Does sdb4 contain any important data?

Comment: Oh sorry! I intended to write sdb4 and sdb7 are my D and E drive of Windows. I use Windows 10 and though my machine does support UEFI I have booted with legacy BIOS.

Comment: Where do I start? The partitions are a mess. Esp for a 1TB HDD. Do you actually need D and E drives for W10? Do you have the W10 and Ubuntu install discs? Do you have a good backup of your important data? As I mentioned earlier, W10 updates can wipe ext4 partitions on MBR disks. Please advise what your total end result should be... as I may recommend switching to UEFI, see if Windows and Ubuntu still boot, and then probably have you start from scratch.

Comment: @heynnema Ubuntu and Win10 are both booting fine. Also as I primarily use Ubuntu, would Windows be able to get updates of about 35gb? As such I have no important data in any Windows' drive.I would like to switch to UEFI but I don't have install discs for Windows and I am not sure if switching from BIOS to UEFI would harm any of my OS. If you could suggest anything, it would be of great help.

Comment: Do you have a full legal W10 license key? You can download a W10 install disc. If so, I'd recommend starting over in UEFI mode with GPT disks. If you don't have a W10 key, then I'd delete sda9/7/8/4 (after backing up any data), then move around the remaining partitions, and create a new NTFS partition for data that can be shared between W10 and Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, so it looks like I'd have to delete 4,7,8 and 9. Is there any way I can upgrade to UEFI without having to delete my Win10 OS? Also, can you explain how to share a single NTFS partition between both Win10 and Ubuntu? I have only seen Ubuntu using ext4 so far.

Comment: Yes, you delete the unneeded partions, review the status, and then complete the final partition resizes/moves. I don't believe that you can convert to UEFI without manually creating an EFI partition, and that wouldn't make sense unless you changed from MBR to GPT partitioning. Ubuntu can read/write to NTFS partitions, but you don't want to do that to your W10 C: drive. W10 can't read/write to ext4 without the use of a special driver... and those tend to corrupt ext4. Keep in mind my comment about W10 updates wiping out ext4 partitions on MBR disks.

Comment: So, how about this. I allot, say 75gb more data to sdba2(Win C drive) that way it will have a breathing space of about of 110gb. Then I delete 4,7,8 and 9 and perform rest of the operations.

Comment: Do the partition deletions first with gparted, then move/resize partitions. Use W10 Disk Mgr app to resize C: and create the common shared NTFS partition. Show me the gparted picture when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

**The current plan of action is...**

- backup all important data
- move any required data to sdb2 or sdb5
- use gparted to delete sda4/7/8/9
- use gparted to resize/move remaining partitions except for sdb2 (Windows)
- add 75G to sdb2 using Windows Disk Management app
- create a new NTFS partition as a shared data partition between Windows and Ubuntu

**A better plan is...**

- obtain a proper Windows license key and install disc
- obtain a Ubuntu Live DVD
- backup all important data
- set BIOS to UEFI
- wipe the disk and change to GPT partitioning
- install Windows
- resize Windows using Windows Disk Management app
- create a shared NTFS partition
- install Ubuntu
- restore data

Answer (score 0):

There is one rule you're forgetting you cannot have more that four primary partitions... So you have to delete one partition and create a new one that covers the entire space + unallocated

Comment: the four primary partitions (inc. extended) applies to mbr/msdos; not to gpt partitioning schemes.

Comment: My bad... I get it now